# Can anyone please tell me why I'm getting an invalid syntax error with my else statement?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to test for prime numbers between 2 and 100, but I am getting an error with my code  and I don't know why. (I am a newbie to python)

```
def function():
  mylist = [1,2]
  count = 0
  for i in range(2,100):
    for j in range(2,i):
      if i % j == 0:
        count += 1
      if count > 0:
        count += 0
        else:
          mylist.append(i)
      count = 0
  return mylist
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like an indentation problem, try this:

```
if count > 0:
  count += 0
else:
  mylist.append(i)
```

In Python, it's very, very important that the code is correctly indented. You see, the `else` keyword *has* to appear at the same level that the `if` keyword. Use a good IDE or text editor to help you catch this kind of errors!

Comment: In general I tended to be obsessive about indentation with Java and JavaScript and really any other language.  This was one of the most welcome aspects of the Python language for me, though with the wrong kind of editor that isn't converting tabs to spaces, these kinds of bugs can be tricky to catch.

Answer (score 2):

Python indicates code blocks with whitespace in the same way that some languages use braces. Your innermost code block would look like this in a language with braces, which might make it easier to see where syntax error is:

```
if (count > 0) {
  count += 0;
  else {
    mylist.append(0);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Else should be indented along the same line as your if statement. Otherwise the else is considered to be inside if condition.